# create slider with gallery thumbnail using swiper.js - nuxt-swiper

Tags: nuxt.js, swiper.js

I want to make a slider with a gallery thumbnail using swiper.js in nuxt project`(nuxt-swiper library)`

so that when the top slider slides, the thumbnail also changes and vice versa.

I also set `controller` for both topswiper and thumbsswier but it doesn't work

when I change the top slides no change happens in the thumbsswiper and vice versa

```
<template>
                <Swiper 
                    class="text-xs w-full h-[90%]"    
                    :modules="[SwiperController]"    
                    :slides-per-view="1" 
                    :loop="true"
                    :controller="{control:thumbsswiper}"  
                    @swiper="setTopSwiper">
                      <SwiperSlide v-for="(img, index) in images" :key='index'>
                        <img src="@/assets/images/products/p4.png" />
                      </SwiperSlide>

                  </Swiper>
                  <Swiper 
                    class="text-xs w-full bg-blue-500 h-[10%]"    
                    :modules="[SwiperController]"    
                    :slides-per-view="7"   
                    :controller="{control:topswiper}"
                    @swiper="setThumbsSwiper"
                    :slideToClickedSlide= "true"
                    :freeMode='true'>
                      <SwiperSlide v-for="(img, index) in images" :key='index' class="slide">
                        <img src="@/assets/images/products/p4.png" />
                      </SwiperSlide>

                    </Swiper>

</template>




<script>
  export default{
    setup(){
      let topswiper = null,
          thumbsswiper = null,
          images= ref(['images1','images2','images3',])

      let setTopSwiper = (swiper)=>{
        topswiper = swiper;
      }

      let setThumbsSwiper = (swiper)=>{
        thumbsswiper = swiper;
      }

      return{
        images,
        setTopSwiper,  
        setThumbsSwiper,
        topswiper,
        thumbsswiper      
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```